# VS 2015 Test Explorer did not show tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, nunit, test-explorer

Alas, I tried all suggestions, which were described but none of them helped me...

- Changed Default Processor Architecture from x86 to x64(Test-> Test Settings)
- Run as Administrator, clean and build solution again
- Updated NUnit, Nunit.TestAdapter and MS.Tesadapter versions
- Tried different versions
- Changed .net from 4.6 to 4.5
  There still no test shown in Test Explorer

Here are my packages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Appium.WebDriver" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" version="16.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" version="16.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" version="16.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.12.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Console" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitProjectLoader" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2Driver" version="3.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2ResultWriter" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.TeamCityEventListener" version="1.0.6" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit.Runners" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.15.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.6.10" targetFramework="net461" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" version="76.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" version="0.24.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver" version="3.150.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net461" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: What does your test look like? Does it have the correct attribute?

Comment: Yup
http://prntscr.com/p9t9i7

Comment: try installing version 2 of nunit test adapter https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTestAdapter

Comment: I did, no changes

Comment: Don't use the NUnit 2 Test Adapter unless you are using NUnit version 2. You appear to be using NUnit 3.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the nunit3 test adapter has been copied to the output directory along with your test assembly.

Comment: It is there, and where did you see NUnit 2 Test Adapter  in packages, i dont use it at all

Comment: The comment about the NUnit 2 Adapter was directed at the suggestion by Josh that you should install it.